# Sitecore Users Group - Milwaukee June Meetup

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

Date/Time (EST): Thursday, June 15, 2017, 5:30 PM EST

Date/Time (EST): Thursday, June 15, 2017, 23:30 PM UTC

Location: 13135 West Lisbon Road, Brookfield, WI

RSVP: https://www.meetup.com/Milwaukee-Sitecore-Developers-Meetup/events/239665897/

Our June meeting will be held at the corporate headquarters of Milwaukee Tool in Brookfield.

Agenda:

5:30 - 6:00pm -- Food, refreshments, networking

6:00 - 6:10pm -- Intro and Announcements from Organizers/Sponsors

6:10 - 7:05pm -- Presentation # 1 - Personalizing for Impact

7:05 - 8:00pm -- Presentation #2 - Troubleshooting Sitecore

Sponsors:

Our location sponsor: Milwaukee Tool - http://www.milwaukeetool.com

Our food and drink sponsor: Paragon Consulting - https://www.paragon-inc.com/

Video links will be provided in the next couple of days after the event.

Presentation #1:

Personalizing for Impact

Personalization can be nebulous; it’s an abstract notion that customers often have a hard time conceptualizing. This session will make personalization pragmatic so customers can actualize the value of personalization and the fullest potential of the Sitecore platform. We’ll begin by defining the three types of personalization within Sitecore, and how you can progress from tactical personalization into the transformational, and really drive value for your business and customers.

Speaker:

Phil Wicklund - Viridian Solutions

Phil has a broad background in both technology and business, including managing a staff of 46+ consultants. He has also written four books (two on Sitecore, and two on SharePoint). Phil was recently awarded Sitecore MVP in the Digital Strategist category for his thought leadership on how to drive value out of the platforms digital marketing capabilities.

Presentation #2:

Troubleshooting Sitecore

Sitecore can be an amazing platform that empowers your organization, except when it's not. Where do you start when your users keep complaining all they see is a yellow screen and some "weird error"?  Come see the tricks of the trade when it's time to pull the server out of the flames and get things back online.

Speaker:

Derek Dysart - DJ Dysart Productions

Derek is going on eight years of working on the Sitecore platform. He's helped global brands both launch and maintain their web presence on Sitecore. Derek is also the host of the Sitecore Podcast, Core Sampler.

Comment: Community Bulletin promotion began 10 hours ago